# Is AA actually flying the 737 MAX?

Tags: boeing-737

In flightradar24 I only see 737 MAX flying from Gol Airlines and Aeromexico, but none from AA.
Is American actually flying the 737 MAX or is FlightRadar24 reporting aircraft types wrong ?
I also see a few MAXes with a Boeing ticker flying in the Seattle area, probably delivery tests.

Answer (score 4):

According to their website, they will start commercial flights using the 737 MAX on 29 December, but will be testing their aircraft on non-commercial flights before than:

> We’ll begin with non-commercial flights in early December 2020 before the official return of the 737 MAX. **On December 29, we’ll resume scheduled service** with 2 flights a day (1 round trip) through January 4, 2021, from Miami (MIA) to New York LaGuardia (LGA). We expect to phase more of the aircraft into our schedule through January, with up to 36 departures from Miami.

<sup>([aa.com](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/737-MAX-return-to-service.jsp), emphasis mine)</sup>